# Find the radius of convergence with a function including log

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Question:**
>
> Find the radius of convergence for $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\log(n)}{n.2^n}.z^n$$

**My attempt:**

**Edit:** After the comments I have noticed I have made many errors, here is my updated attempt

Use the ratio test

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log(n+1)}{(n+1).2^{n+1}}.\frac{n.2^n}{log(n)}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\log(n+1).n}{2.(n+1).\log(n)}$$

How would I proceed to take the limit of logs?

**Edit 2:**

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{2n+2}.\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\log(n+1)}{\log(n)}=\frac{1}{2}.1=\frac{1}{2} $$

Would this be correct?

Comment: How do you define the radius of convergence of a series which is not a power series?

Comment: Sorry! Corrected now

Comment: $\log(n)\leq n-1 \leq n$ so $R\geq 2$

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite follow. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Now, please review the "ratio test".

Comment: And beware that the identity $(\log x)/(\log y)=\log(x-y)$ is ludicrous.

Comment: "How would I proceed to take the limit of logs?" $$\frac{\log(n+1)}{\log n}=1+\frac{\log(n+1)-\log n}{\log n}=1+\frac{\log(1+1/n)}{\log n}=1+\frac{o(1)}{\log n}\to1$$

Comment: Thank you for that, however why does my ratio test converge to a $\frac{1}{2}$ and not 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of convergence of a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ with complex coefficients is
\begin{equation*}
R \,=\, \liminf_{n\to\infty}\, |a_n|^{-1/n}~.
\end{equation*}
$($If $a_n=0$, then $|a_n|^{-1/n}=+\infty$.$)\,$
In your case the radius of convergence is
\begin{equation*}
R \,=\, \liminf_{n\to\infty}\, \left|\frac{\log(n)}{n\cdot 2^n}\right|^{-1/n}
\,=\, 2\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}(\log(n))^{-1/n}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n}
\,=\, 2\cdot 1\cdot 1
\,=\, 2~.
\end{equation*}

Answer to the question in a comment:

> I see, that is using the root test, why doesn't my method with the ratio test work?

Your computation, when turned upside down, is correct:
\begin{equation*}
R \,=\, \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|
\,=\, 2\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\!\frac{n+1}{n}
\cdot \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{\log(n+1)}
\,=\, 2 \cdot 1 \cdot 1
\,=\, 2~.
\end{equation*}
The ratio test works only if the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n/a_{n+1}|$ exists $($the limit is taken in the extended real half-line $[0,+\infty]$, so it may legitimately be $+\infty$$)$. The root formula works always, thus always gives the radius of convergence, provided that you are able to compute the $\liminf\,$.

Comment: I see, that is using the root test, why doesn't my method with the ratio test work?

Comment: @THISISIT453 - I added the answer to this question to the original answer. **Typesetting remark.** For a product dot in LaTeX use \cdot, not the ordinary dot (that is, the full stop).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

If $|z| > 2$ it's easy to see that this series is divergent. Can you see why?

If $|z| < 2$ it's easy to see that this series is convergent. Can you see why?

So the radius of convergence is $2$.

Comment: Aaaah... Thanks for referring to **the intrinsic definition of the radius of convergence** rather than jumping on its incidental characterization in terms of liminf of powers of the coefficients of the series.